# How do I install linux-manta_3.4.0-6.25.tar.gz?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-emulator

I am trying to install Ubuntu Touch but I have missing the package linux-manta_3.4.0-6.25.tar.gz.
when I decompress it i didn't find the configure and make files to install it.so how can I install it

Comment: Is there a readme? what is in the extracted directory?

Comment: -@bodhi.zazen : there is readme file, i dont understand how can i do it
@KasiyA this file is not like the normal .tar.gz files, the not "configure" file or make file

Comment: [linux-manta_3.4.0-6.25](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/linux-manta/3.4.0-6.25/+files/linux-manta_3.4.0-6.25.tar.gz) this is the link file and try it

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download deb packages

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-headers-3.4.0-6-manta_3.4.0-6.25_armhf.deb

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-image-3.4.0-6-manta_3.4.0-6.25_armhf.deb

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-manta-headers-3.4.0-6_3.4.0-6.25_armhf.deb

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-manta-tools-3.4.0-6_3.4.0-6.25_armhf.deb

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-manta-tools-common_3.4.0-6.25_armhf.deb

Install them with Software Centre

Comment: it says "wrong architecture 'armhf' "

Comment: Linux-manta: This package contains the Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on  Nexus 10. Nexus 10, has a Exynos 5 dual-core processor based on Cortex A15,the Cortex-A15 processor is built around the ARMv7-A architecture.

Comment: thnx for informations, so help us to solve this problem